# Why won't my Raspberry Pi connect using SSH when NRF24L01 or ATTiny85 are Connected via SPI?

Tags: spi, nrf24l01

As the question states, my Pi (3 B+) won't accept SSH connections (times out) when I have either my NRF24L01 or ATTiny85 boards hooked-up. I hook both up (at different times of course) to pins 17, 19, 21, 23 and 25 for SPI communications.

When the pins are already connected at boot up, the SSH terminal always times out; but I can unhook the pins before boot-up and SSH works fine. I then have to put all of the pins back on to continue what I was intending to do. Very annoying to say the least!

My question is: Why would this be the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, I've determined that it **must** be a power-supply issue.

I bought a new power-supply out of desperation and the problem went away. I guess my old power-supply was on it's last-leg and just couldn't keep up with the requirements of powering additional components. It seems it could barely even keep up with the Pi itself since the Pi was running headless.

Just thought I'd let others know...

Regards,